# How to calculate probability from logistic regression using interaction effect parameter?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, interaction, regression-coefficients

I have a logistic regression (logit link) model that I use to estimate probabilities. In the absence of interaction effects this formula is given in a lot of references as

$$p_i = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\Sigma\beta_ix_i}}$$

However, I can find no reference to an explicit formula for probability estimates when the model parameters contain interaction effects. I currently have these coefficients from an analysis in R, but need to calculate the probabilities in a C++ application (and unable to do so). Could anyone provide the formula for the general case with multiple interaction effects please (or a reference to it / source code) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is accurate even when there are interactions. You can define a new variable as the product of two others (or more than two).  Suppose you have two variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ and want to include their interaction in the model. Just create $X_3 = X_1X_2$ and proceed.  (This generalizes in the obvious way for more interactions).

The actual coding may depend on whether the variables are continuous or categorical and, if they are categorical, on what parameterization you want to use, but the principal is the same and coding requests are off topic here.

Comment: Many thanks - this is exactly what I needed to hear.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting Peter's answer, if it helped.